# como mostrar todas las palabras que se ecuentren en una lista anidada

Tags: python

```
lista=[['fanta 3 lts'], ['sprite'], ['Coca 3 L']]

for i in lista:
    match=[s for s in lista if 'spr' in s]
print(match)
```

estoy sin poder resolver como encontrar todas las palabras de una lista anidada ingresando las primeras letras. Suponiendo que yo no conozco la lista de productos y al ingresar un caracter 'x' me muestre como resultado todos los productos que inicien con ese caracter. Lo resolvi si pongo por ejemplo lista[1] la encuentra pero yo quiero que me busque en toda la lista y no especificando la posicion porque en teoria yo "no conozco" la posicion de la misma.

Comment: En tu for, iteras en la lista, pero buscas en la lista en general. Solo cambia `[s for s in i if 'spr' in s]`

Comment: @Sr1871, eso devolvería cualquier `string` que contenga `spr`, por ejemplo `absprf` lo consideraría como válido

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buen día,

El error es que en tu comprensión de listas estas iterando en `lista` y no en `i`, pero también hace falta validar que empiece por x caracteres.

Si utilizas `if 'spr' in s` cualquier `string` que contenga "spr" se consideraría válido. Para únicamente devolver los `strings` que empiecen por "x" caracter(es) puedes utilizar [`startswith()`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_startswith.asp).

También podrías obtener los elementos en una sola línea

Ejemplo:

```
lista=[['fanta 3 lts'], ['sprite'], ['Coca 3 L'], ['abspra']]
nueva_lista = [s for i in lista for s in i if s.startswith('spr')]
print(nueva_lista)
```

Esto imprime:

```
['sprite']
```

Comment: muchas gracias!

Comment: Buen día @Nicolas, si la respuesta te fue útil no olvides aceptarla, de esa forma ayudas a otros usuarios a encontrar la solución a preguntas similares y al mismo tiempo ayudas a la comunidad a mantener abiertas únicamente las preguntas que no han sido resueltas. [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)